# Массив огромных размеров

Tags: java

Есть олимпиадная задача, ограничение по памяти 256 мебибайт. Нужно создать матрицу 100000 х 100000. Когда я делаю это, то возникает OutOfMemoryException. Как бороться?
UPD: Спасибо за ответы, понял идею.

Comment: Точно мебибайт?)

Comment: @Vennic, https://ibb.co/GHwT2CG, задача J.

Comment: Я думаю, вам нужно алгоритм дейкстры почитать (подсказка уже вначале задания), и варианты реализации. Не думаю что с матрицей такой вы вложитесь в 256 Мбайт , потому что ваша матрица уже тянет на 9,5GB. А если делать её кеширование на диск - 2 секунды исчерпаете быстро.

Comment: Вначале, я советую очень почитать теорию графов, и ознакомится с основными операциями в графе. Возможно... вам не нужна полная матрица - тогда вам поможет Dictionary. У Dictionary один ключ правда... если думаете решать таки через матрицу, то думаю вам Dictionary. http://vscode.ru/prog-lessons/dictionary-in-java.html или что-то ещё из семейства ключ-значение KeyValue

Comment: Типичный вопрос- [XY problem](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/795/291659). Матрица такая вовсе не нужна.

Comment: Большие массивы приходится хранить в виде баз данных на дисках. Ну, или использовать сервера с ОЧЕНЬ большим ОЗУ.

Comment: ваша проблема в том, что вы не знаете иных представлений графа, кроме матрицы смежности. Погуглите "представление графа в памяти".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А у тебя все 10000000000 значений будут одновременно присутствовать? Если нет, то прежде всего посмотри в сторону разреженных матриц. И "сжать" в битовое представление тоже можно - нужно будет всего-навсего написать простенький собственный класс и переопределить в нем operator[]. В общем, задача легко решается. Только нужно подумать над теми вариантами использования твоей матрицы.
с++

```
        int main(){
        vector< vector< bool > > verified( 100000, vector<bool>( 100000, false);
        cout << verified[5][5]<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Да, все 10000000000 значений. И я должен иметь доступ к каждому из них.

Comment: Безполезный ответ. По условию задачи нужно вложится в 256 Мб и 2 сек, такая матрица... ну чисто поболтать. Если в битах - ваша матрица около гига:)